# Which script from /etc/init.d/ started the process?

Tags: process, daemon, init

Let's say we have a PID of a process and we know that it was started by init during startup. How do we find the script name that started it?

One way is to run `grep $PROCESS_NAME /etc/init.d/*`, but that solution is neither bulletproof nor very elegant.

Another one would be to run `service --status-all` and there is a good chance that the PID will be returned by one of the services, but that's even less elegant than the previous solution

EDIT:

The OS is RedHat/Ubuntu.

Let's suppose we have sshd running with PID 2083 like so:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2083     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The parent of it is `init` and I *guess* that it was started with the command `service sshd start` during bootup, but if we have something that cannot be easily guessed, for example a convoluted startup command or because of an obfuscated `/etc/init.d/somedeamon` script - how do we find the `somedeamon` script, knowing only the PID?

Comment: This is OS dependent. What OS are you running?

Comment: You seem to be mixing terms somewhere.  If init runs the script that starts the process then the process (daemon) that started it would be `init`.  If you're looking for a process that had started this one.  You could look at `PPID`.  If this is not what you're asking then please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Sorry about the confussion. I've rewritten the question and I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to follow the PPID chain backwards is with the `pstree` tool:

```
pstree -p PID
```

This will show all the parent processes of the specified PID, for example:

```
$ pstree 42284
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 00199 jack /sbin/launchd
   \-+= 00254 jack /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm -psn_0_90134
     \-+= 00309 root login -fp jack
       \-+= 00310 jack -bash
         \--= 42284 jack vim site.txt
```

Comment: Except when that doesn't work, which is not all that uncommon. Many daemons are started with a double fork (the script forks a launcher which forks the daemon thread then exits), so the PPID of the daemon is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow the PPID chain backwards from the process you are interested in. But if, say, A launched B, B launched C, and B finished, now C's parent is `init` (PID 1). To access information about process PID, you do `ps -l -pPID`.